# get a value of string between quotation

Tags: string, vba, collections

I have a string of a value got from a external database.
I want to get an item of collection which built by key as string.

```
 Dim stations As New Collection
    Dim trains As New Collection
    For i = 1 To 60
        Dim new_station As New station
        With new_station
            .id = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(0)
            .name = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(1)
            .t = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(2)
            .name_t = new_station.name & new_station.t
            .x = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(3)
            .y = S_stationsDataSet.Node_Table.Rows(i - 1)(4)
        End With
        stations.Add(new_station, new_station.name_t)
    Next

    Dim a, c As String
    Dim b As Single
    For i = 1 To 62 Step 2
        Dim new_train As New train
        With new_train
            a = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(1)(i)
            b = S_trainsDataSet.T.Rows(1)(i + 1)
            c = a & b
            *new_train.src = stations.Item("c")*
        End With
        trains.add(new_train)
    Next
```

I have to put the two quotation "" to define I will get the item by key and of course it is invalid value as it return "c", not the value of string c. 
How can this be solved?

Comment: Uh, did you try `stations.Item(c)`? Why put a variable name between quotes?

Comment: Argument 'Index' is not a valid value.

Comment: Use the debugger to check what the value of `c` is. Then check whether that item exists in the collection.

Comment: value of c is exactly what I want .. the item exists in the collection .. 
when I replace c with its value between " " it works .. any ideas

Comment: Note that `a` is not defined `As String`, though that shouldn't matter. Note also that the `With new_train` is not necesssary, but if you do use it then `.src= ...` is sufficient (but this also shouldn't matter).

Comment: is there a way to return the value of a string anywhere that I can use ??

Comment: c does not need to be in quotes, it is a string already,  you are currently passing `c` as itself not its value. If you want `""` around the value of c then use `"""" & c & """"`

Comment: If `c` is for example "the train", and `stations.Item("the train")` works, then you can force `c` to be a string and only a string by `stations.Item(String(c))`. If that doesn't work then something else is wrong.

Comment: the compiler need the key in quotes to read it as key not index as I think .. so I need the quotes around the value of c .. and I just tried """" & c & """" .. but it didn't work too, very grateful for you

Comment: @PaulOgilvie : Error 1 'String' is a class type and cannot be used as an expression.

Comment: Sorry, I mean `CStr()`.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie, you are amazing it works , thank you and for every one helped me